# using Lloyd's algorithm for anchored partitioning

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, voronoi

I can use Lloyd's algorithm to partition a polygon into n polygons. Suppose I divided the polygon below into 5 polygons using the above algorithm and I get this:-

[image]

But I wanted to do anchored partitioning meaning I wanted each sub-polygon to include at least one boundary point like this:

[image]

Are there modifications to the algorithm already available that can help me achieve that? How to ensure anchoring?

It would be very helpful if you could cite some existing Matlab/python codes rather than pseudocode? The code I used for above is from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41507-lloydsalgorithm-px-py-crs-numiterations-showplot) which does the plain vanilla implementation.

Comment: It might be enough to simply initialize the points on the boundary. You can also check what cell violates the constraint and move the points closer to the closest boundary until the cell touches it. Not sure if this will converge to something reasonable, though.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit more information about the problem you are trying to solve using this algorithm? Do you need the Voronoi cell of each point to border a side of the square at every iterative step of the algorithm or do you want to have an end result with all cells bordering a side? Because I was thinking in the first case, at each step you can add one of  the vertices of the interior cell to the Voronoi diagram, recalculate it and then unify the interior cell with the cell of the new point and declare it a new, enlarged cell of the interior point.

Comment: If the second scenario is more relevant, then you can put a potential function on the square whose gradient when added to the update of each point during a step of the algorithm will alter the iterative dynamics a bit so that the region in the middle of the square repels points, pushing them towards the sides of the square, while the sides slightly keep points inside the square.

Comment: I want to have an end result with all cells bordering a side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion: A simple attempt. Define a potential function `U(x, y)` on the square. Something  [like this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_wavelet)  You can choose the parameters so that its minimum is a circle that is almost the circle inscribed in the square. Or feel free to choose a different potential. Given the points `p1 = [x1; y1], p1 = [x1; y1], ... pn = [xn; yn]`, forming the 2 x n matrix

```
P = [p1 p2 ... pn];
```

let the function for one step of Lloyd's algorithm be

```
P_out = LA(P_in)
```

i.e. given the points `P_in = [p1_in  p2_in  ...  pn_in]` it generates their Voronoi diagram, then calculates the centroids of each Voronoi cell `p1_out,  p2_out,  ..., pn_out` and moves the input points to the new output, centroid points `P_out = [p1_out  p2_out  ...  pn_out]`.
Then you can apply a repositioning along the minus gradient of the potential, i.e.

```matlab
function  P_out = GR(P_in)
   P_out = P_in - gradU(P_in); 
end
```

where `GRAD = gradU(P_in)` is the function that calculates the gradient vectors for each column-vector `P_in(:,j)` and produces the 2 x n matrix GRAD of gradients.

So your algorithm will actually be the composition

```matlab
P_out = LA(GR(P_in));
```

Maybe then the points will favor the periphery of the square, avoiding the middle part and thus will eventually have Voronoi cells touching the boundary? I chose a potential with the assumption that in this case the vector gradient field is irrotational, so there will not be some kind of circulating dynamics emerging, but the algorithm will converge to some cetntroidal equilibrium configuration (it sound believable but I am not sure about that).